# Is a useEffect cleanup necessary in the top level component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Do I need to clean up the subscription in the code example if this code is running in the top-level component and the component being unmounted means the app is being closed? When I try to log out a comment in the clean up I never see it actually being written out in the console. I couldn't find a scenario where it would actually run and, therefore, I feel like I might as well remove it. Is it worth keeping it around for some reason?

Thank you.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
      "change",
      _handleAppStateChange
    );

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: You better just keep it. In case your component is used somewhere else in the future.

Comment: @Ploppy used somewhere else? What do you mean? The component is the top-level component, if it gets unmounted the whole app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying this just for top-level component or general for cleanup function?

I will go with the second thought. Since it was a big problem for me when I started React. I recommend reading this article [Cleanup-useEffect](https://dev.to/pallymore/clean-up-async-requests-in-useeffect-hooks-90h) helped me a lot.

Comment: I know how the cleanup works. I'm asking in the specific case where the useEffect containing the cleanup is run in the top-level component.

Comment: I think it does not matter on the top-level component but as @Ploppy said, there is no harm to using it.